Terrestrial planet with rings has occasional meteor showers that cover much of the habitable space, what would the native species do to survive them?
One of the most important planets in my story's world is Australis, a habitable terrestrial planet with rings and a single moon. The rings contain a valuable metal ore which is mined to be used as a potent fuel. This ore was discovered in its pure form several centuries ago when a few pieces of the rings strayed off from their orbit and fell into the planet's atmosphere, and its discovery and resulting application made the Argonites, the native species of the planet, advance technologically much faster than the other races.
On top of this, a previous ring-meteor shower occured over four millennia before which spread some of the metal across Australis's single continent, before any humanoids discovered it (All sapient beings in this universe derived from one planet and spread out over the galaxy). The native plants incorporated it in their systems as they grew in this hypermetal-rich soil, as did the animals who were eating these plants; as a result, they became tougher and more aggressive than their counterparts on other worlds which lack the element.
So here you see the problem. Several times in the past, there have been meteors striking most of the surface as the result of the rings' existence, and these strikes are more or less random (there's no observable cycle of "quiet years" then "year or two of rocks raining down from the sky" then "quiet years"). How would I keep this as a worldbuilding point but also have a thriving sapient species living beneath, completely undisturbed (this isn't even touched on as a concern in the story)? More specifically, why did the meteor shower that led to the discovery of the hypermetal not obliterate the developing Argonite civilization before they had a chance?
Of course, by the time they started mining it, they probably developed stabilizers of some kind to keep the rocks in place while they collected the ore, but the question is what they could've done before that.

We are not a brainstorming site. Questions asking us to generate ideas for you are not permitted here. I suspect that different species will come up with different adaptations. Can you instead, do the brainstorming yourself and ask us for help with a specific problem you have encountered?

This is not an answer (hence it being a comment), but the idea of a terrestrial planet holding a ring large enough to create meteor showers when disrupted is already a giant red flag for me.  The overwhelming majority of the particles in Saturn's spectacular rings are smaller than pebbles, and Saturn has a gas giant's Roche limit to tear apart the source material.  A terrestrial planet would have to capture a fairly enormous body inside its own geostationary orbit to have rings that could engender meteor showers when disrupted.

(Also, if there are periodic meteor showers - even in the range of thousand-year intervals - the rings aren't going to last very long unless they're a very recent feature, cosmologically speaking.)

@sphennings sorry about that. I thought I had worded it the right way as a question, but I'll take this down if you think it's the wrong thing to say on this site.

@jdunlop ok, makes sense. Which means I'm just forced to either remove the concept or handwave it in rather than have an actual scientific explanation, which i'm ok with.

A useful short explanation as to why terrestrial rings are unlikely: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11733/why-earth-does-not-have-rings/11735#11735
As an added small detail - once you get into the habitable zone of a star, solar wind and radiation pressure tend to blow away, evaporate, or deorbit ring material-sized objects in a hurry.

I see no meaningful way to distinguish "brainstorming" from the way nearly every question here is answered.  It's far easier simply to answer it.

For future reference, please note that questions asking what would characters or organizations do (actions, decisions, motivations, etc.) is specifically prohibited in the [help/on-topic].

@MikeSerfas The difference is Stack Exchange's [help/dont-ask] prohibitions against open-ended questions and/or questions leading to all answers having equal value. If the question has so few conditions, restrictions and limitations that a best answer cannot be reasonably selected objectively (vs. "I like this one the best!"), then it's brainstorming and prohibited. We're much more forgiving as-is and right now than Stack Exchange wants us to be.

@JBH We're talking fictional worlds here, but I think my answer could be better than others, so that prohibition doesn't apply to this one.  And I never see this notion referenced with the questions where it might apply ("I have a magic chipmunk, what should I kill it with?" mace? rifle? pointed stick? nuke?...)

@MikeSerfas Actually, I vote to close "what's the best X for Y?" questions regularly, although I intentionally try not to close new users, favoring instead an effort to educate and get them to edit their posts (which almost never works). The real problem with this Q is that it's asking for possible actions of people, which is specifically prohibited in the [help/on-topic]. Your answer is a Frame Challenge, which is always an exception and, honestly, never a rationalization for not closing a question.

@jbh I'm not asking for you to give me ideas. My question was poorly worded, and I'm sorry about that. But what I was trying to ask was not "what would my species do in this situation" but rather "why didn't the cataclysm wipe them out before they had the chance to discover the reasons behind it."

@KeilahH Ah. Thanks for the clarification. We regret the reality, but Stack Exchange's rules make asking questions on an inherently subjective and imaginative topic a bit... tricky.... How you ask a question is insanely important here. Thanks for your understanding. If you're ever unsure, test your question in our Sandbox. Cheers.

@JBH all right, thanks for understanding! I'll use the Sandbox next time, it sounds insanely helpful.

You're more likely to get hit by lightning.
Over 40 million lightning strikes hit the U.S. alone each year.  It is a worry that comes to mind when we hear the booms, and quickly forgotten.
A planetary ring delivering a trace element to the surface would not need many devastating impacts.  Consider how few bombs it would take to deliver enough plutonium to the U.S. to make a difference to us - while those typically would be explosive, the contamination with the metal itself wouldn't require detonations.  In fact, the meteors could most typically burn up as shooting stars in the atmosphere, and the metal would nonetheless fall to the surface and be taken up into the ecosystem.
Given that your ring metal is a potent fuel, enough to make a major difference to your ecosystem, I would suggest you consider an isotope of Copernicium with approximately 180 neutrons (Cn-291 and Cn-293, specifically), from the putative "island of stability"  Look up the references from the Wikipedia article.
It is plausible that if such an isotope is stable, it might have an extremely low critical mass - low enough that living organisms might be able to accumulate it for specific purposes, without exposing themselves to tremendous practical difficulty or large amounts of radiation.  Alternatively, the nucleus may be so large, and the surrounding electrons drawn in so close to it, that some chemical manipulation of the atom's charge can alter its rate of decay, if the precise isotope used is a bit rich in protons and thus vulnerable to electron capture.
Because the element is itself unstable, it is possible that the ring has arisen not from a Roche limit violation, but from the innate instability of an object containing the element.  It might be warm from radioactive decay, outgassing its inert components, and periodically undergoing explosions as the transuranic element builds up in its crust to a critical level.  We have no plausible means of generating transuranic-rich objects like this, but it could be artificial in origin, or arise from a very unusual cosmological event (cosmic string modifying matter near it, wormhole between universes, whatever).
Imagine you found a piece of ore the size of a pea that could power a steam engine or, with a bit of chemical modification, concentrate itself to the point of creating an explosion suitable for diverting a river.  (Note that a very small critical mass should lead to a very small nuke - while the potential for someone carefully machining this to make a fountain pen that can bring down the United Nations should disturb us, it is not so likely that the initial discovery of the material, producing only a "fizzle yield", will wipe out every witness)  Inevitably there would be some progress in technology as a result, even if there are only a few thousand such precious nodules in a whole country.

That part about the meteors disintegrating in-atmosphere and delivering the element to the ground anyway makes sense! Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, thank you. Now I know my characters can look up at the ringed sky without fear of possibly being flattened tomorrow, heh.

And, interestingly enough, after looking over my ideas again, the element I had chosen was one away from your suggestion of copernicium. I had selected atomic number 111, which is known in our world as roentgenium.

@KeilahH - sorry, I forgot to edit that part when I was writing it - I found a reference that it's specifically Cn-291 and 293.  (though I don't know why the even-numbered isotope would be less stable here)
